# Does installing themes affect the battery life of laptop?

Tags: themes, laptop, battery

I am getting poor battery performance on my laptop. Is it because I've installed new themes and icons?

Comment: Which themes ? Normally they won't be a resource hog. But when some theme author gets " very creative " that could be a problem. More the code to run , more the need for power.

Answer (score 1):

Installing themes does not affect the battery life of a laptop. An installed theme constitutes files on your laptop. A theme that is in use is defined by the appearance as described in these file. Whether you use a standard theme or a different theme does not make any difference in power consumption.